# Android, textview onclick crash

Tags: android, onclick, textview

i have my class which extends baseActivity, all works well except a simple onClick on a textview :-|

```
TextView labelName_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelName);
labelName_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // animazione automatica al click
        LinearLayout contenitore_cibo_l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_container);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) contenitore_cibo_l.getLayoutParams();
        System.out.println(lp.topMargin);
        //contenitore_cibo_l.startAnimation(makeAnimation_ordini(400, 25));
    }
});
```

when i click, it crash with:

```
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.web_pos.android.OrderActivity$4.onClick(OrderActivity.java:296)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-27 12:30:22.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your logcat appears to be missing some error lines...Specifically the ones that specify which line the program crashed on.

Comment: whether you are taking layout param of the container layout or not???

Comment: Make sure that the `LayoutParams` are from `LinearLayout`. Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the type of `LayoutParams` you are using. From the logs it appears that you are using `android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams`. Change it to `android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and it should work smoothly. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it works! hope it doesn't involve some other problem, but it seems no

Comment: It should not. We have to take/import the LayoutParams of the container layout as rightly pointed by Bhupendra below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to always take the layout param of the container layout for which you want to change the layout , suppose  i want to change the button layout which is in the linear layout so i have to take linear layout params

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your import statement for LayoutParams.

Instead of importing  android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams, you should import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams